# Unable to run PySpark after upgrading Java

Tags: python, java, macos, pyspark

The following code generates the error:

```
def init_spark() -> SparkSession:
    """
    This function initialise the Spark Session
    :return: None
    """
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .appName("Data Quality ETL for Cars") \
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    print("Spark Initialized", "\n")
    return spark
```

The error I get is

```
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I know there is no issue in pySpark and code, other than upgrading Java. Below are my Java related details on Mac.

```
➜  ETL_DQ_Cars git:(main) ✗ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home
➜  ETL_DQ_Cars git:(main) ✗ java --version
java 19 2022-09-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19+36-2238)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19+36-2238, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Python

```
➜  ETL_DQ_Cars git:(main) ✗  python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

Comment: isn't jdk 19 too high for spark? 'Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.7+ and R 3.5+. Java 8 prior to version 8u201 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.2.0. For the Scala API, Spark 3.3.0 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x)' quoted from official doc.

Comment: @Young I did not know that.  I had upgraded Java for something else and it broke spark. What should I do then?

Comment: @Young if I use the spark within docker, will I still have the same issue?

Comment: @Volatil3 I suggest you to look for a compatible version for your spark, python and java. You should keep all your driver and executor share one same version. you can try launch it through docker, i think you can find a docker well configured for your case.